# Using rails code inside jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails, In my rails application, on change of checkboxes, the text-area is getting populated with the contact numbers separated by commas. I want to check the condition that if the message limit in the account is "n" than the contact number being populated in the text area should not exceed "n" and a proper alert should be shown.
I tried to google it but could not find a way to have rails code inside jquery, to fetch the message limit from database and check the contact number being populated in the text-area has not exceed the message limit. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do from this description. Please edit your question to include the code you tried to use, which may shed some light on your goal.

Comment: Could you paste some code so that we can get a clear view of your goal.

Comment: If I understand your question you are trying to do something impossible, rails is a back end language what means it runs on the server side, Jquery is a Javascript library, and Javascript is front end, so it runs on the browser, there is no way to run Rails inside Jquery script.

Comment: Why do you want to fetch text area character limit every time from database. You have to get it from backend on initial load and store on client side. Do all validation for character limit and displaying error message on client side using Jquery. It doesn't make any sense to use Rails for client side validation. However on submission of the form you have to validate it on server side too. I hope this helps, Thanks